# VS2013 Remote load test agent can't connect to controller

Tags: c#, .net, azure, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have a Windows 8.1 PC joined to the company domain with the VS load test controller installed.

I have a Windows 2008 R2 VM on Windows Azure with the VS load test agent installed.

I have set up communication over port 6901/TCP between the two machines. When I try to configure the agent to connect to the controller, it passes all but one test and fails completely. In the error log, I find this line repeatedly:

```
I, 2014/01/07, 19:47:43.134, Could not get the status from the test agent. Exception: Failed to connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here is a screenshot of the status window from the test agent configuration:

[image: Test Agent Configuration Status Window]

So any ideas what the heck is going on?

Comment: not even one comment?